# Uniform projections for several TIF images

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

I'm trying to build a global hydrological model which needs to import external geographical images (e.g., DEM, river network and aquifer thickness etc.)

I've obtained these files but find they are in very different projections (see the figure below, actually I'm not sure whether it's the projection problem or not, but the images are very strange). And importing them to the model results in fatal errors. Has anyone encountered such problem and how can I make their geoinfo consistent?

[image: The figure I got:]

The projection info extracted using code

```
data = gdal.Open(data_path)
data_proj = data.GetProjection()
```

is:

First panel:

```
PROJCS["Cylindrical_Equal_Area",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Cylindrical_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```

Second panel:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],AXIS["Longitude",EAST],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

Third panel:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],AXIS["Longitude",EAST],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

The geospatial extent extracted using code `data.GetGeoTransform()`
is:

```
(-20037507.0672, 11113.9, 0.0, 6324895.855799999, 0.0, -11113.9)

(-180.0, 0.00833333333333333, 0.0, 83.99999999999994, 0.0, -0.00833333333333333)

(-180.0, 0.08333333333333333, 0.0, 90.0, 0.0, -0.08333333333333333)
```

Comment: Did you get any metadata when you obtained the data? Are the coordinate systems defined properly? Do you have other GIS software available, for example ArcGIS (Pro or Desktop), QGIS etc.? I would think that making the rasters coalesce would be more explainable in a package that other users are comfortable with. If you don't have other GIS software then consider QGIS, it's open source (no cost) and quite powerful, there are online tutorials.

Comment: I put the geoinfo in my question post as there is word limit here. And for the file conversion, I did not use ArcGIS or QGIS... The figures above were converted from the raw data using python's gdal and rasterio directly. Do I have to use the GIS tools to help fix this problem?

Comment: Yes, use GDAL_Warp to transform the cylindrical CRS into geographic to match the others and then GDAL_Translate with -projwin of the smallest extent and -tr to match the largest cell size. This will give you rasters with the same origin and cell size.